# Turn & into amp for URL's imported into database

Tags: php

I import some URL's from an XML feed.

```
$myurl = 'http://www.myurl.com?value1=val&value2=val&value3=val
```

The problem is when I try to validate my code, I need `&amp` instead of `&`

Comment: @Matt — No, not urlencode, that is for encoding data to be inserted into a URL. The `&`s are dividing the query strings up, they aren't appearing as data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `&amp;` when you insert the text into an HTML or XML document, not when it goes anywhere near a database.

If you are generating HTML, then put your text through `htmlspecialchars()` to turn it into HTML.

If you are generating XML, then use an XML library to generate it. Don't build it by mashing strings together.

Comment: Ty very much, just tried it but it does not change the & into &amp;

Comment: I did it like this: echo htmlspecialchars($myurl);

Comment: I right clicked my code also and it works, but I think html validator does not see it

Comment: @webmasters by validator, you mean what?

Comment: It is server side code. It doesn't care what the client is (unless you explicitly make it do so). The data will be encoded for validators and browsers. Turn on the Show Source option of the validator and make sure that you are encoding all the pieces of data.